# Problema com ThreadStatic do C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, thread, threadpool

Possuo um sistema onde a autenticação dele guarda um token em uma propriedade ThreadStatic. Acontece que segunda feira, ele começou a distribuir os tokens incorretamente (após atualização do windows server).

> Fiz a aplicação abaixo para testar o cenário

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static String texto;

    public String teste(String valor) {
        if(valor != null && !valor.equals("")) {
             texto = valor;
        }
        return texto;
    }
}
```

> Cenário

Caso eu chame a URL `http://localhost/home/teste?valor=oi` eu obtenho o resultado oi. Se eu chamo o mesmo método `http://localhost/home/teste` sem passar o atributo valor hora ele me retorna vazio, hora ele me retorna preenchido e caso eu chame outra vez passando como valor `tchau` ele vai ficar me retornando esse valor de forma randômica. Esse comportamento é normal com o `ThreadStatic` ou pode ser que tenha modificado algo na atualização do .NET?

Obrigado.

Comment: O pool não está sendo reciclado?

Comment: Então @LeandroAngelo começou segunda feira a aplicação funciona já faz mais de um mês. Não foi modificado nenhuma configuração.

Comment: Você está usando IIS? Já tentou reiniciar a aplicação?

Comment: @PedroGaspar sim, tentei. Mas não rolou, é uma aplicação MultiTenancy de momento estamos fazendo esforços para usar o Token direto na Request.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute), o atributo `ThreadStatic` "indica que o valor de um campo estático será único para cada thread".

E, pelo que li nesse artigo de um blog da própria Microsoft:

> ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.5, IIS 7.0, and IIS 6.0 - Thomas Marquardt's Blog
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/07/20/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-5-iis-7-0-and-iis-6-0/

eu entendi que as requisições no ASP.NET podem usar uma mesma thread mas também podem ser executadas em threads diferentes. Então, me parece que o que está acontecendo é que nos seus testes algumas threads são criadas, e cada uma tem o seu valor para o campo estático `HomeController.texto`, por causa do atributo `ThreadStatic`.

Aqui nessa discussão em um fórum do MSDN:

> [ThreadStatic] and the threadpool - MSDN Forums
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d464b27-ac8c-4800-9d23-d8ddadb41931/

o moderador Reed Copsey Jr sugere o uso da classe `ThreadLocal<T>` ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1)), ao invés do atributo `ThreadStatic`. E, usando o exemplo da documentação, você pode até criar um novo campo estático nessa sua classe `HomeController` para verificar se as threads são diferentes mesmo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
   [ThreadStatic] public static String texto;

   // Variável Thread-Local que produz um nome para uma thread.
   public static readonly ThreadLocal<string> NomeThread = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
   {
      return $"Thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
   });

   public String teste(String valor) {
      // Substitui as duas verificações anteriores pelo método String.IsNullOrEmpty().
      if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor)) {
         texto = valor;
      }
      return $"Texto: '{texto}' / Nome da thread: '{NomeThread}'";
   }
}
```

Você também poderia simplesmente eliminar o atributo `ThreadStatic` desse campo, se quisesse um valor único para toda a aplicação, porque segundo essa resposta do SO<sup>EN</sup>, campos estáticos são *thread-safe*:

> c# - Thread safety on readonly static field initialisation - Stack Overflow
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/12159883/8133067

Mas, por que você não deixa esse campo como um campo normal, ao invés de estático? Dessa forma cada objeto `HomeController` teria o seu valor, não?

Comment: Olá Pedro, então. Na realidade a aplicação é separada em 16 classLibrary, e uma dessas classLibrary é a de Business. A classLibrary de Business usa uma outra classLibrary a de Auth, hoje a camada de negócios necessita saber quem é o usuário que tá executando a ação. Não é só uma WebApi, tem serviços do windows e outras coisas envolvidas. Mas recentemente houve esse problema, que coincidiu com a atualização do .NET. Pois no mesmo dia em que ele atualizou o problema passou a ocorrer. Mas você tem razão, não é a solução ideal identificar uma ação com atributos estáticos mesmo que em threads.

Answer (score 0):

### Sim, esse é o comportamento normal

Você não controla qual thread que executa seu Controller. Cada requisição pode ter uma thread nova, uma thread repetida, e você não tem como saber.

### Como solucionar

Para guardar um dado específico de um usuário, você utiliza [sessões](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg454582.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).